# Seeing "on Behalf of" in system generated emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use a PHP mailer with of my online programs and recently when I look in outlook I see
'crazyphil@host.validns.com on behalf of My Mailer [no-reply@mydomain.com]' when I receive emails from any of my domains.

Previously the crazyphil@host.validns.com was nobody@host.validns:

```
Return-path: <nobody@host.validns.com>
Received: from nobody by host.validns.com with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <nobody@host.validns.com>)
```

It used to be fine like that, but something on my hosts side changed and now I get the 'on behalf of'. Anyone know why this is occuring now, and not before (since all that changed was nobody to somebody!) and how to resolve it?

Thank you,

Phil

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to set the from header in your mailer.

Mail servers will usually append their own if one isn't found.

in normal php it'd be something like

```
$headers = "FROM: 'fromname' <from@example.com\r\n>";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I already had the *From* in the header, but I overlooked one difference in the header:

```
Sender: <crazyphil@host.validns.com>
```

This line popped up in all emails from my host, even those sent by the cron daemon.
Getting this removed resolved the issue.

Thanks though!

--Phil